# Header position:sticky background-color issue

Tags: html, css

The background of the page is a `linear-gradient` and the headers have `position: sticky`. As the page gets scrolled down the header is overlapping the image with its background being transparent but I want the header background to have the same `linear-gradient` scheme as that of the page. Thanks in advance

Current - 
[image]

Expected - 
[image]

code - https://jsfiddle.net/wveufyn2/3/

**[EDIT]**
We cant add the same `linear-gradient` to the header as its out of sync with the overall color scheme.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html {
  background: linear-gradient(218.78deg, #20233A 33.97%, #3A2034 100.71%);
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.flex.spaceBetween {
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: linear-gradient(218.78deg, #20233A 33.97%, #3A2034 100.71%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Done.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question this won't work as the overall background color continuity breaks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kohansalism/8ojur7y6/
Check it, it's without any bg breaks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move this header with you isted of position: sticky

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: but if that section let say 'Top' get scrolled completely then the header should also be gone.